# Python fill zeros in a timeseries dataframe and keep existing values

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

I have a list of dates and a dataframe. Now the dataframe has an id column and other values that are not consistent for all dates. I want to fill zeros in all columns for the ids and dates where there is no data. Let me show you by example:

```
      date     id     clicks    conv    rev
     2019-01-21 234      34        1     10
     2019-01-21 235      32        0     0
     2019-01-24 234      56        2     20
     2019-01-23 235      23        3     30
```

date list is like this:

```
     [2019-01-01, 2019-01-02,2019-01-03 ....2019-02-28]
```

What I want is to add zeros for all the missing dates in the dataframe for all ids. So the resultant df should look like:

```
    date     id     clicks    conv    rev
   2019-01-01 234      0         0     0
   2019-01-01 235      0         0     0
      .                .         .     .
      .                .         .     .

   2019-01-21 234      34        1     10
   2019-01-21 235      32        0     0
   2019-01-22 234      0         0     0
   2019-01-22 235      0         0     0
   2019-01-23 234      0         0     0
   2019-01-23 235      0         0     0
   2019-01-24 234      56        2     20
   2019-01-23 235      23        3     30
       .               .         .      .
   2019-02-28  0       0         0      0
```

Comment: `your_data_frame.fillna(0)` and why just 0, have a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html and from `sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer`

Comment: Please read the question carefully @SmartManoj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `MultiIndex`, also is necessary convert `list` and column `date` to `datetime`s:

```
dates = ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-21','2019-01-22','2019-01-23', '2019-01-24']

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pd.DatetimeIndex(dates), 
                                  df['id'].unique()], names=['date','id'])

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index(['date','id']).reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index()

print (df)
        date   id  clicks  conv  rev
0 2019-01-01  234       0     0    0
1 2019-01-01  235       0     0    0
2 2019-01-21  234      34     1   10
3 2019-01-21  235      32     0    0
4 2019-01-22  234       0     0    0
5 2019-01-22  235       0     0    0
6 2019-01-23  234       0     0    0
7 2019-01-23  235      23     3   30
8 2019-01-24  234      56     2   20
9 2019-01-24  235       0     0    0
```

Verify dtypes:

```
print (df['date'].dtype)
datetime64[ns]
print (mux.levels[0].dtype)
datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: will this code keep the existing non-zero values? I have a similar code but it copies zeros against all dates

Comment: @Nofy - What is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: Data columns (total 11 columns):
dtypes: float64(2), int64(7), object(2)
Yes, I verified, I am getting all zeros with your solution as well

Comment: @Nofy - For me working nice, are converting both dates to datetimes - in list and also in column?

Comment: Didn't convert the column to datetime. Now it's working. well caught!